# Accessing JSON data array of objects returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Practice</title>

</head>

<body>


    <script>
        const endpoint = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Miserlou/c5cd8364bf9b2420bb29/raw/2bf258763cdddd704f8ffd3ea9a3e81d25e2c6f6/cities.json';

        const cities = [];

        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(data => cities.push(...data));


        console.log(cities)
        console.log(cities[0])
        console.log(cities[0].city)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

***The code is supposed to get data from JSON, push it into the cities array with spread operator then play with the cities array to access its contents.***

But I run this code on a browser and open console,
`console.log(cities)` shows an array of objects.
But when I'm trying to access the object inside, it returns undefined.
I tried to copy property path on chrome console and it shows `[0].city`.

I expect a result of

> {city: 'New York', growth_from_2000_to_2013: '4.8%', latitude:
> 40.7127837, longitude: -74.0059413, population: '8405837', …}

when I run `console.log(cities[0])`

and get

> 'New York'

when I run `console.log(cities[0].city)`

unfortunately it shows

> undefined

and

> index.html:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'city')
> at index.html:26:31

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is an asynchronous operation, meaning by the time the cities is populated your code has already executed the console.log statement. To fix this make the following change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Practice</title>

</head>

<body>


    <script>
        const endpoint = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Miserlou/c5cd8364bf9b2420bb29/raw/2bf258763cdddd704f8ffd3ea9a3e81d25e2c6f6/cities.json';

        const cities = [];

        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(data => cities.push(...data))
            .then(() => {
                  console.log(cities)
                  console.log(cities[0])
                  console.log(cities[0].city)
             });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```